# MFTF Custom Helper get stepKey variable value

Tags: magento2, testing, mftf

I'm trying to write a Custom Helper, according to https://devdocs.magento.com/mftf/docs/custom-helpers.html
To perform Tax Calculations and return a Fee.
According to documentation you can return a value and it would be stored in the stepKey

Does anybody knows how to do this, there's a lack of documentation, I checked Magento vendor folder in search of examples, and I didn't found any.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of this line is :

```
<ModuleName>/Test/Mftf/Helper
```

You have to create your Helper file on that location into the extension directory.